# How can I fetch a user balance from the database

Tags: database

How can I fetch a user balance from the database and insert in the users list in the admin section?

Not sure what you guys need me to show you in order to help me :)

Comment: You need to show a bit more context to your question. Where is your code? What database or server are you using?

Comment: Thanks Here is the user list page in admin :

Answer (score 0):

user list in admin :

```html
<?php echo $header;?>
<div id="dashboard">
 <div class="container">
<div class="row"><br/></div>
<div class="panel">

 <div class="panel-header"><?php echo $LANG["WBS_ADMIN_USERS_INDEX_MANAGEMENT"];?></div>

<div class="panel-content">
<div class="col-md-12">
<!-- ADMIN QUICK STATS -->



<table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><?php echo $LANG["WBS_ADMIN_USERS_INDEX_FNAME"];?></th>
          <th><?php echo $LANG["WBS_ADMIN_USERS_INDEX_LNAME"];?></th>
          <th><?php echo $LANG["WBS_ADMIN_USERS_INDEX_EMAIL"];?></th>
          <th><?php echo $LANG["WBS_ADMIN_USERS_INDEX_PHONE"];?></th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>


   <?php if ( !empty ( $users ) ) { ?>
   <?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
    <tr>

      <td><?php echo $user['up_first_name'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $user['up_last_name'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $user['user_email'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $user['up_phone'];?></td>
      <td>
     <a href="<?php echo HTTP_SERVER_ADMIN ?>users/profile.php?user=<?php echo $user['user_id'];?>" class="btn btn-success"><?php echo $LANG["WBS_ADMIN_USERS_INDEX_PROFILE"];?></a>
     <a href="<?php echo HTTP_SERVER_ADMIN ?>clickfraud/index.php?user=<?php echo $user['user_id'];?>" class="btn btn-danger"><?php echo $LANG["WBS_ADMIN_USERS_INDEX_CLICK_FRAUD"];?></a>
     <a href="<?php echo HTTP_SERVER_ADMIN ?>ads/filter.php?user=<?php echo $user['user_id'];?>" class="btn btn-info"><?php echo $LANG["WBS_ADMIN_USERS_INDEX_CREATED_ADS"];?></a>
      </td>

    </tr>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
   <?php } ?>


      </tbody>
</table>

<?php if ( $paginator['rows'] > 10 ) { ?>
<div class="row"></div>
 <?php echo $paginator['pager'];?>
<?php } ?>



<!-- END ADMIN QUICK STATS -->
<div class="row"><br/></div>
</div>
<div class="row"><br/></div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php echo $footer;?>
```

Comment: Now I want to add the user balance in the list (even if I need to use the phone culum i dont mind not seeing the phone number)

Comment: But the result ii need to fetch would be in a different table in the database